# Five outlets not working

Tags: walls, receptacle

My home was built in the late 60’s. An outside porch light was on a timer that recently broke. I replaced it and it works fine, however, now I have no power to five outlets.  One is outdoors and the other four are inside. All are along the same wall or vicinity. These do not have gfci resets. Do I need to start replacing one outlet at a time to find the culprit?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box where the timer's located?

Comment: While working, did you happen to have any arcs or shorts that gave buzzing sounds or a flash?

Comment: No buzzing or arcing.  The replacement went really well and continues to work. Now I’m wondering if these outlets are actually on the same chain as the light switch.  I have shut off and on all the breakers that may have tripped and still no power.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with daisy chained outlets. I have learned over the years to find the first non working fixture closest to the breaker panel or last working one and usually find a bad back stab. Or wire nut. Since you just did some work you may not have connected all the hots or neutrals solidly where you did the work. So there 2 paths forward depending where the chain originates from. If the power to these outlets comes from the timer box 1 of the wires may not be making a connection in a wire nut. If the source is from the other direction find the first failed or last working outlet.

Comment: I've had similar where I didn't get all wires properly connected in a wire nut and 1 was just hanging inside but not touching. Now I give the wires a twist with the pliers prior to the wire nut.

Comment: When I have bundles of wire I strip them long and twist them with pliers then cut and twist the wire nut on, good suggestion.+